# How To Bind Array Of Images In c# To XAML Image Source?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I developing windows phone 8 game application using XAMLDirect3D.

I need to store list Of images in array. On every button click image must be change. it's my requirement.

I try imageBrush  with following code for store images in array and Pass the Array img to Xaml it's work fine .I try same code for image but it's not working.

plz tell it's correct way or any other way present for my requirement.

XAML :

```
   <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush x:Name="imgBackground" Stretch="Fill"></ImageBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
```

C# :

```
string[] imgChange;

 imgChange = new string[4];
 imgChange[0] = "bg1.png";
 imgChange[1] = "bg2.png";
 imgChange[2] = "bg3.png";
 imgChange[3] = "bg4.png";

imgBackground.ImageSource = (ImageSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString("Images/" + imgChange[bgImgIndex]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

may this will help you.

```
imgBackground.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/" + imgChange[bgImgIndex], UriKind.Relative))

                             or
imgBackground.Source= new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/" + imgChange[bgImgIndex], UriKind.Relative))
```